# Transaction in LLBLGen Pro

Tags: transactions, llblgenpro

I am using LLBLGen Pro 2.5 with self-servicing.  If I want to add some rows into my tables within a transaction and then update the first row I added, do I have to add that first entity into the transaction object again?

Here is a fictional example of what I mean:

```
Dim objCustomer as New CustomerEntity()
Dim trans as new Transaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, "AddRecord")
objCustomer.FirstName = "John"
objCustomer.LastName = "Locke"
objCustomer.DateCreated = DateTime.Now
trans.Add(objCustomer)
objCustomer.Save()

Dim objOrder as New OrderEntity()
objOrder.CustomerID = objCustomer.CustomerID
objOrder.OrderDate = DateTime.Now
trans.Add(objOrder)
objOrder.Save()

objCustomer.FirstOrderID = objOrder.OrderID
trans.Add(objCustomer) 'DO I DO THIS??????
objCustomer.Save()

trans.Commit()
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may be better off asking this at the LLBLGen support forums http://www.llblgen.com/tinyforum/ rapid top notch support is provided...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to add it again.  You can simply just do the save again.  I use Adapter instead of Self Servicing, so I would have made sure to fetch my customer data upon saving, but I'm not sure if that is a requirement for self servicing or not.